# I need to read a number, then I need to read a string with whitespaces but my program does not let me read a string it skips the second scan

Tags: scanf

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

```
char user_string[100];
int n;

printf("Enter a number greater than 0:");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter %d strings with white spaces: ", n);
scanf("%[^\n]", user_string);
printf("The string you entered is: %s", user_string);

return 0;
```

}

output:
Enter a number greater than 0:5
Enter 5 strings with white spaces: The string you entered is:

Answer (score 0):

**Failed to consume `'\n'`**

`scanf("%d",&n);` does *not* consume a trailing `'\n'`.  That prevents the following `scanf("%[^\n]", ....` from reading anything.

Allow the `scanf("%[^\n]", user_string);` to consume leading white-space: `scanf(" %[^\n]", user_string);`  (space added).

**Missing width**

`scanf("%[^\n]", user_string);` is worse than [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Do not use `"%[^\n]"` without a width limit.

```
// scanf("%[^\n]", user_string);
scanf(" %99[^\n]", user_string);
```

**Missing return value check**

Add a check.

```
if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", user_string) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Bad input\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or other action.
}
```

---

Tip: Read user input with `fgets()`.  Do not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

---

Detail: "then I need to read a string with whitespaces" is a faulty goal.  In C, a *string* is a sequence of characters followed by a *null character*.  Users do not normally ever enter a *null character*.

A more correct goal may be "read a *line* ...".  (Characters up to and including a `'\n'`.)